# Where is UC Browser's history stored in Android? or what is URI for reading UC Browser's history and Bookmark data?

Tags: android, browser, browser-history, bookmarks, uc-browser

I know that UC browser's bookmarks are stored in `/data/data/com.UCMobile.intl/databases/bookmark.db`. I have been searching for history database for a very long time but i could not find it.  Will be really happy if someone could help.

I would also like to know the **URI** for UC Browser to read history and bookmark.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you contacted the developers of this product and asked your questions, what did they tell you?

Comment: I haven't contacted the developers of this product. Does it require any extra permission to read the bookmarks and history from my app?

Comment: "I haven't contacted the developers of this product" -- then perhaps you might consider doing so. "Does it require any extra permission to read the bookmarks and history from my app?" -- you would need to contact the developers of this product and ask them if they have a documented and supported API, and if so, what permissions it might require.

Comment: I don't know where it's strored, you can decompile apk and look for it. But Uc Browser uses cloud computing, I mean it's rendering page on cloud and send back it to phone in another format. So you should not look for .html files.

Answer (score -2):

History is in device `/data/data/com.ucmobile/ucmobile/userdata/`, here are the two files of history

- `history.ini`
- `historyurl.ini`

Comment: Didn't find anything in android 9